# Finding the length of a video in Java and ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg

Is there a way to find a length of a video using Java? I understand we can make use of ffmpeg to generated thumbnails and encode videos. But can it be used to get the length of the video?

Thanks and Regards
Abishek R Srikaanth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just call `ffmpeg -i filename` it will print information about the file and you can parse the output to get needed information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ffprobe** utility for this purpose. **FFProbe** normally comes with your **FFMpeg** distribution, please check the */bin* folder. You can specify in what format **XML** (there is even an XSD for FFProbe output http://www.ffmpeg.org/schema/ffprobe.xsd) or **JSON** you want **FFProbe** to give you info about the video file.

So, for example:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format -show_streams video.mp4 -print_format xml=x=1 -noprivate
```

will give you output in valid XML.

Please, look at the *duration* attribute of a 'video' stream section. This will be the duration of the video in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
(avconv -i $FILE_NAME 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | sed 's@\..*@@g' | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }'
```

---

Use this command to get the duration in seconds

avconv and ffmpeg are same . In Ubuntu 13.10 and above ffmpeg is replaced by avconv